# Webscraping Scopus with lxml.html

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml.html, scopus

I'm trying to webscrape Scopus with lxml.html (ultimately to create a list of document titles), but it seems no data is being stored from the page.content; the resulting list(tr_elements) ends up empty.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

url = 'https://www.scopus.com/results/citedbyresults.uri?sort=plf-f&cite=2-s2.0-84939544008&src=s&nlo=&nlr=&nls=&imp=t&sid=fdbfeac69ab848bdff16425dc6937ffc&sot=cite&sdt=a&sl=0&origin=resultslist&offset=1&txGid=b63ddae0b71deb5a4615640f49db9904'
page = requests.get(url)
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')
```

Since the inspect element shows that rows have varying classes(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QUvw.png) I've also tried running it with `tr_elements = doc.xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'searchArea')]")` specifying which rows to parse, but this also ends up in an empty list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Access denied | [www.scopus.com](http://www.scopus.com) used Cloudflare to restrict access